# How to get a 3DS model with animation into Silverlight web application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-5.0, 3dsmax, 3ds

I have created a 3D human character using 3dsMax 2012. 
Then I have used morpher technique to animate the facial expressions in the character.
I'm going to embed this character in to a silverlight web application. 
I'm using Silverlight version 5 and Visual studio 2010.

To get the 3D model I will be using silvermotion method.
http://www.postvision.net/SilverMotion/Default.aspx
But when I use this it needs a .3DS file format in order to view the character.
When I export the character into .3DS file format (with the facial animation which I created in the .max file format ) it wont include the animation I used.
I have used the animation in polygons (animated as the character talk) by using keyframes.

If somebody could help me quickly reply me soon. If there's another way to get the animation with a 3D model in to a silverlight web pages please reply me. Thank you.

Comment: You can use the XNA part of Silverlight 5 and maybe the sgMotion library to support animation.

Comment: I haven't done it though, but here's a resource about SL5 3D: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/10/04/silverlight-toolkit-september-2011-for-silverlight-5-what-s-new.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on the following web link:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/maxim/2009/03/31/daily-tip-how-to-import-3d-model-to-wpf-from-3d-max/